# Evaluating Repeated Values Across Separate Tables (And Counting Them)

Tags: statistics, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to conduct some statistical analysis of some imported tables. The tables have information (ID's) that correspond to other tables. I'm wanting to output how many times a certain ID comes from another ID.

Example:
Table 1

| Source Name | Source ID |
| --- | --- |
| Source-1 | S-001 |
| Source-2 | S-002 |
| Source-3 | S-003 |
| Source-4 | S-004 |
| Source-5 | S-005 |
| Source-6 | S-006 |

Table 2

| Strategy Name | Strategy ID |
| --- | --- |
| Strategy-1 | I-001 |
| Strategy-2 | I-002 |
| Strategy-3 | I-003 |
| Strategy-4 | I-004 |
| Strategy-5 | I-005 |
| Strategy-6 | I-006 |
| Strategy-6 | I-007 |

Table 3

| Source ID | Strategy ID |
| --- | --- |
| S-001 | I-001 |
| S-001 | I-003 |
| S-001 | I-006 |
| S-001 | I-001 |
| S-002 | I-001 |
| S-002 | I-007 |
| S-002 | I-006 |
| S-003 | I-001 |
| S-003 | I-004 |

In this example, I would want to know the number of sources (Table 1) in which Strategy 1 (I-001) is found. This means that I need to go through ALL of Table 3 in order to find out this information.
** Note: I-001 is found twice in S-001, so I also need to make sure that I don't double-count S-001.**

I've tried making a WHILE loop that goes the whole length of Table three, but but have been unable to successfully make that work. I am fairly new to MySQL, so I would love all the help and advice I can get. I am also working in MySQL Workbench, if that makes a difference.